# Issue with AHK mapping

Tags: autohotkey

I'm learning about AutoHotKey

The first effort has worked fine

```
!+Up::
MouseClick, left, 340, 65
return
```

This means when I press ALT and shift with the up cursor, my mouse clicks at given coordinates.

I want to have the same funcationlity but with the num keys

```
!+Numpad3::
MouseClick, left, 462, 65
return
```

Sadly, this has no effect and I can't see why. When I press ALT+SHIFT+Num2 the mouse doesn't move.

Comment: Does it work with anything else than numpad keys? It wouldn't surprise me if you cannot use numpad keys for shortcuts (especially not shortcuts with ALT in them). I'd test making the shortcut without ALT and trying a bunch of other keys to see if that works.

Comment: It was fine when I used CTRL+NumKey :(

Comment: That suggests to me that it might be related to using ALT+Numkey, because that is already an existing shortcut. In general, it's not a good idea to use shortcuts that interfere with existing ones. This indeed cause issues like you describe. Therefore, I'd suggest accepting a change in the shortcut keys.

Answer (score 1):

!+Numpad3 has no effect because
If you press Shift+Numpad3 the result is NumpadPgDn if the Numlock is on and Shift+NumpadPgDn if the Numlock is off.

e.g.

```
; Press Alt+Shift+Numpad3 to send a if the Numlock is on and A if the Numlock is off:

Alt & NumpadPgDn:: Send a
```

Try also:

```
; Alt+Shift+Numpad3:
Alt & NumpadPgDn:: MouseClick, left, 462, 65
```